# Hortonworks Sandboxes in a cluster

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I'm new to Hadoop ecosystem and i'm trying to understand how a cluster works. Until now, I've been using Hortonworks distribution to test anything in a single-node mode. Now I'm wondering - if it's possible to connect two VM's (running on one PC physically) so that one will be NameNode and the other one DataNode (i'm not sure if they should be separated). I found a similar tutorial for Cloudera, so I guess it's possible in theory.

If it's not even a good idea to run two Hadoop VM's on one PC, - then what is the most painless way to configure and run it on two separate PC's?

Answer (score 0):

May be it will be useful.  This post "Setting up a Hadoop cluster"
http://gbif.blogspot.ru/2011/01/setting-up-hadoop-cluster-part-1-manual.html

Comment: Try to add some information about what you know rather than just adding some link which would give the answer. That helps the question author to understand better.